# django prefetch_related for list of instances

Tags: django, django-orm

I was wondering if it is possible to prefetch related fields for already instantiated django objects.

for example let's say I have a group of instance of `MyModel` which I got from different sources (so I couldn't prefetch related the queryset at the first place) and I want to access related fields. I want to prefetch the fields for my list of objects in only 1 DB call.

Is there an elegant way to populate my instance prefetch cache? I was imagining something like

```py
prefetch_related(list_of_instances, [field1, field2, field3])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By searching in the documentation, I found that django already has a function for that:

> `prefetch_related_objects(model_instances, *related_lookups)`
> Prefetches the given lookups on an iterable of model instances. This is useful in code that receives a list of model instances as opposed to a QuerySet; for example, when fetching models from a cache or instantiating them manually.

> Pass an iterable of model instances (must all be of the same class) and the lookups or Prefetch objects you want to prefetch for. For example:

```py
from django.db.models import prefetch_related_objects
restaurants = fetch_top_restaurants_from_cache()  # A list of Restaurants
prefetch_related_objects(restaurants, 'pizzas__toppings')
```